# GIt reset done and committed again but unable to view the SSDT package files

Tags: git, ssis

Hi I have pulled a branch from remote and unable to see the latest changes in my visual studio.

I did a '`git reset --soft HEAD^`' and I could see the files.
I did a '`git add .`' and '`git commit -m "changes made"` ' and still unable to see the files in the Visual studio.

What could go wrong. Could anyone help?

[image: status]

Answer (score 0):

Your current status shows:

- HEAD moved to the previous HEAD commit
- the index changed
- the working tree unchanged (that is what `reset --soft` does: move HEAD only, without touching the working tree or the index)

You should at least:

- commit
- `git restore -- .`

That would make sure the working tree reflects the latest changes.
Then switch back to Visual Studio and refresh your solution.

After that, make sure your IDE is set:

- on the same folder repository
- on the same branch in that repository.

Comment: I had done a git commit after reset done which I have mentioned earlier. I did it again. it still does not reflect the changes.

Comment: @AjayAshok I meant, your screen shot does not reflect a git commit. After a commit, your git status should be clean. Make sure your IDE is on the same branch as your terminal session.